# Get row number reading HTML in R

Tags: html, r, html-parsing

I'm trying to read a webpage which contains products (twelve elements per page) and prices (regular and discount, which can be of three different types) from a supermarket.
To accomplish this, I'm using functions like html_nodes and html_text.
When reading prices, I've to use html_text because the content of values is not inside the nodes.
For example:

```
url<-"https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse/"

parsed_url<-read_html(url)

regular_price<-parsed_url %>%
        html_nodes('.atg_store_newPrice') %>%
        html_text(trim=TRUE)
```

And I get something like this (35 elements, because every price is repeated three times in the page unless one product has 'loyalty' discount, in which case appears two times only):

```
[1] "PRECIO CONTADO\n\t\t\t                  \n \n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n \n \n\n\n\n\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n $219.00"
```

But for one type of discount price, I get only one (that depends on the moment and the page the query is done anyway) value:

```
discount_price<-parsed_url %>%
        html_nodes('.first_price_discount_container') %>%
        html_text(trim=TRUE)

[1] "25%\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r \r \r \r \r\t\r \r \r \r \r \r \r\t\r\t\t\t\r\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$52.99"
```

So, the question is, there's a way to know the row of the text that html_text function is returning, in order to control to which product belong the discount that is not present regularly in the html structure?

Thanks,

Comment: It would help if you posted the `parsed_url`

Comment: Hi @CarlBoneri, I've added the url and parsed_url as per your request. Thanks!